# WebView's restorePicture method - Preventing webview to reload the page

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

As I say in the topic, I want my WebView to prevent from reloading the webpage when another activity comes to the foreground or just when the orientation is changed. The reason why is because the WebView content is generated by Javascript/AJAX almost completely. After searching on a couple of forums, I found out many people suggested to use "saveState" and "restoreState" methods, but when I look the documentation, it says:

> Please note that this method no longer restores the display data for this WebView. See savePicture(Bundle, File) and restorePicture(Bundle, File) for saving and restoring the display data.

So, here I was using that savePicture and restorePicture as it follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

... some other lines ....

```
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            loadInicialWebUi();
        }else{
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            boolean restoredPic = mWebView.restorePicture(savedInstanceState, new File("savedDisplayWebView.temp"));
            Log.d(TAG, "restored Picture:" + restoredPic);
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mWebView.saveState(savedInstanceState);
    boolean savedPic = mWebView.savePicture(savedInstanceState, "savedDisplayWebView.temp");
        Log.d(TAG, "saved Picture:" + savedPic);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

And well, those logs were revealing that it saves the picture, but it couldn't restore it. I suspect there might be something about the File references, but I couldn't think of a better way of getting the reference of the File I created when saving the state.

Anyone thrilled?
I would appreciate any clues/suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Manuel.

Answer (score 0):

I would load the page in `onCreate()` and put this attribute on your Activity in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

This will prevent your Activity from being restarted when orientation changes. And since your Activity loads the page in `onCreate()`, bringing another Activity to the foreground won't cause you to reload the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it would work for screen orientation changes, as I read on other articles, but when I send an intent to open an activity (specifically the VoiceRecognition), using the same Task and with the history enabled, as soon as it gets back it loses the content dynamically generated, that's why I was interested on that specific method (savePicture).

Comment: I'm sorry, I had some errors in my code so the WebView was losing the generated content. Now it's OK, but I'm still curious about this savePicture and restorePicture methods.